# condensing rows in Redshift SQL expression

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with employee changes over time, each rows with start_date and End_date.
My goal is to condense the rows to only have rows when there's an actual change.
I have accomplished it for the most part, except in certain cases, when the employee moves back to where he/she was before. When this happens, the start dates takes on the start date before the change.
I have more columns than status that change but for the sake of this example, we only use status.

| Status | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018-01-01 | 2019-02-09 |
| A | 2019-02-10 | 2019-09-30 |
| B | 2019-10-01 | 2019-11-03 |
| A | 2019-11-04 | 2020-01-15 |
| A | 2020-01-16 | 2023-03-31 |
| A | 2023-04-01 | 9999-12-31 |

I want:

| Status | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018-01-01 | 2019-09-30 |
| B | 2019-10-01 | 2019-11-03 |
| A | 2019-11-04 | 9999-12-31 |

My SQL:

```
with all_rows as (
    select 
        my_emp_id,
        cast(start_date as date),
        cast(end_date as date),
        status,
        lead(status) over (partition by my_emp_id order by cast(start_date as date), cast(end_date as date)) as new_status
        
    from my_emp_table
   where  my_emp_id = 'abcde'
      order by cast(start_date as date), cast(end_date as date)),
      condensed as ( 
    select 
        my_emp_id,
       status,
       first_value(cast(start_date as DATE)) over (partition by my_emp_id order by cast(start_date as date) rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)  as FINAL_START_DATE,
             cast(end_date as date) as final_end_date
     from all_rows)
  
select Start_date, 
       end_date, 
       status, 
       final_start_date, 
       Final_end_date
from condensed
where  (status <> new_status or new_status is null)
order by start_date;
```

I tried this:

```
with all_rows as (
    select 
        my_emp_id,
        cast(start_date as date),
        cast(end_date as date),
        status,
        lead(status) over (partition by my_emp_id order by cast(start_date as date), cast(end_date as date)) as new_status
        
    from my_emp_table
   where  my_emp_id = 'abcde'
      order by cast(start_date as date), cast(end_date as date)),
      condensed as ( 
    select 
        my_emp_id,
       status,
       first_value(cast(start_date as DATE)) over (partition by my_emp_id order by cast(start_date as date) rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)  as FINAL_START_DATE,
             cast(end_date as date) as final_end_date
     from all_rows)
  
select Start_date, 
       end_date, 
       status, 
       final_start_date, 
       Final_end_date
from condensed
where  (status <> new_status or new_status is null)
order by start_date;
```

but expected this:

| Status | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2018-01-01 | 2019-09-30 |
| B | 2019-10-01 | 2019-11-03 |
| A | 2019-11-04 | 9999-12-31 |

Comment: Are the dates really not DATE datatype already??? Please, don't store dates as strings :(

Comment: Look up the Gaps and Islands problem. You'll find some good resources.

Comment: it's a staging table. but yes they will be stored as date in our core table.

Comment: Are there ever any gaps in the timeseries?

Comment: Thanks dfundako I was looking for the words to describe this issue!

Comment: There are no gaps

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  coerced
AS
(
  SELECT
    my_emp_id,
    status,
    CAST(start_date AS DATE)  AS start_date,
    CAST(end_date   AS DATE)  AS end_date,
    LAG(status)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY my_emp_id
            ORDER BY start_date
      )
        AS previous_status
  FROM
    my_emp_table
),
  partitioned
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = previous_status THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY my_emp_id
            ORDER BY start_date
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                 AND CURRENT ROW
      )
        AS emp_status_partition
  FROM
    coerced
)
SELECT
  my_emp_id,
  status,
  MIN(start_date),
  MAX(end_date)
FROM
  partitioned
GROUP BY
  my_emp_id,
  status,
  emp_status_partition
```

Comment: thanks for it, but it's not wokring:
It's giving me



| A        | 2018-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
| B        | 2019-10-01 |2019-11-03  |

Comment: It's also asking for a frame clause so I put:
 SUM(CASE WHEN employee_status = previous_status THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY custom_token_3
            ORDER BY start_date
            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
      )
        AS emp_status_partition

Comment: @titanic_logic It would be `CURRENT ROW`, rather than `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution.
I had to do a grouping of each sequence and then find the min start_date for each grouping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).